# How to enter a Visual Studio 2010 evaluation extension key after evaluation period expiry

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I had downloaded and installed VS 2010 Ultimate evaluation for 30 days. It allows me to get a 60-day extension if I register. My register just ended.

2 days ago, I got the extension key by registering but did not enter it because I thought I should wait till the product evaluation period expires.

Now, when I open up VS 2010, it gives me a dialog box with only two buttons:

a) Learn more about upgrading. This takes me to the same page that allows me either to buy or generate an extension key.

b) Close. This closes VS 2010.

How do I enter in the extension key now?

Answer (score 1):

In order to update the product key you need to be logged on with administrator privileges. Try logging on as an admin and the go to the control panel > uninstall/change a program > Enter the product key > click "upgrade."

Here is a link from MSDN on how to do it for VS 2008 trial editions. It is the same for VS 2010:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442563(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I did the same exact thing and it looks like the only option I could find after tons of googling is redownloading and installing the latest version to use your new key with. Here is the page I found with links to the downloads:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb984878.aspx

NOTE: I have not yet downloaded this and tried the key I received from the 60 day extension but will let you know if this works when I get a chance to DL it in the next couple days unless anyone else can confirm.

Answer (score 0):

(Probably too late, but here's an idea that may help someone...)

Try setting your computer's date back to a point in time when your trial was valid (e.g. 1 month ago). I've just tried this on an expired 2010RC and it ran happily, allowing access to the Help>Register menu option.

Of course, attempting to register in this way may detect that you're running "in the past" and refuse (at which point, try setting the clock back and see if it'll let you retry) - but it's worth a try before going through the pain of reinstalling the whole thing from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Try "Help -> Register Product". It can be your answer